# SQL command/query for average by column IDs?

Tags: sql

So I know I can use the SQL avg() function for average, but how do I break it down by actual ID's in the column?

Say I have 10 different id's and I need to get an average from each of them in one query, how would I do that as simple as possible?

Comment: look at "group by"  please show your table schema.

Comment: `group by` should do it.

Comment: Do you mean ten different columns called ID_1, ID_2 etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for using `AVG` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT AVG(SomeColumn), ID
FROM YourTable 
GROUP BY Id
```

Comment: Yea thanks guys GROUP BY was what I was looking for. I looked at using that previously but when I went on a site describing it I thought I had to use the aggregate function with it as well which I didn't understand.

Comment: @CraigAnderson -- np, glad I could help!